# Exception not falling in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wrote a function in ruby on rails model like below

```
def sorted_exp
  begin
    exp.order("currently_active = true DESC, TO_DATE(to_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') DESC")
  rescue 
    exp.order("currently_active = true DESC")
  end
end
```

but there are few entries in `to_date` column due to which exception falls like 'september 2018'. When I tried to handle exception in `model`, it failed, and does not go in the `rescue` section. I don't know why it does not catch the error in model here, and why it does not return a query in the rescue section.

The exception raised is the following:

> PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid value "se" for "MM"

Comment: are you sure that value 'september 2018' is raising an exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `sorted_exp` method, the output of the query is not being used. Rails actually executes the call to the DB when the value of the call is being used. In this case, the value of this is probably being used in some other function and the error is being raised from there, pointing to this line: `exp.order("currently_active = true DESC, TO_DATE(to_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') DESC")` 
I'm not sure of your exact use case, but the only way of catching the exception in this block would be to use values that the query is supposed to return, like counting the number of objects returned(Again, it depends on your use case).
For example, the following query raises an error inspite of being in a `begin..rescue` block:

```
begin
  User.order("TO_DATE(users.created_at, 'MONTH-YYYY') DESC")
rescue
  puts "In rescue block"
end
```

This raises the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function to_date(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist

However, when the output of this query is used in the `begin` block itself, the exception gets caught. For example:

```
begin
  sorted_users = User.order("TO_DATE(users.created_at, 'MONTH-YYYY') DESC")
  count = sorted_users.count
rescue
  puts "In rescue block"
end
```

The output for this is:

> In rescue block

This is because the query was actually executed in the `begin` block itself, and hence, got caught by our `rescue` block.